# How does QUIC encrypt packets containing multiple CRYPTO frames?

Tags: protocol-theory, transport-protocol

TCP is slowly being replaced by QUIC and I'm implementing a component that looks at QUIC packets to extract the server name indication from initial packets. The code is working fine, assuming that: (1) the UDP datagram contains just one QUIC packet plus maybe some padding, (2) the QUIC packet contains just one CRYPTO frame.

Obviously, the TLS ClientHello can be so large that it won't fit to a UDP datagram. A reasonable implementation would in that case fragment the ClientHello into at least two packets in at least two datagrams (one packet per datagram), which contain one CRYPTO frame each. In this case, decryption is simple, according to [Section 5.3 of RFC9001](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9001#section-5.3), the packet number is XORed to the initialization vector of the AEAD algorithm (which in the case of initial packets is AEAD_AES_128_GCM).

However, an unreasonable implementation could:

- Create UDP datagrams that contain multiple QUIC packets. This should be easy to implement too, as each QUIC packet in a UDP datagram has a different packet number field, ensuring I can get the initialization vector used for AEAD_AES_128_GCM, and the initialization vector is different for each packet.
- Create a UDP datagram that contains one QUIC packet but that QUIC packet contains multiple CRYPTO frames. This is what I'm having trouble with.

I tried to read RFC9000 and RFC9001 carefully, to ensure how a QUIC packet with multiple CRYPTO frames in it is handled. I can imagine several possibilities:

1. Use the same initialization vector (containing same packet number information in it) for each CRYPTO frame. However, this could be insecure for other packets than initial packets, because then you can XOR the ciphertexts, which would be a XOR of the plaintexts, revealing you some information about the relationship of the two plaintexts.
2. Concatenate the CRYPTO frame payloads, (en/de)crypt them as one continuous string, and break them again into multiple frames. This seems the most logical way to use cryptography for different CRYPTO frames in a single QUIC packet, after all the data is continuous in memory so using cryptography for it as a continuous string seems logical.

So far (2) seems the most logical way to do this. However, RFC9001 doesn't include test packets for the case where a single QUIC packet contains multiple CRYPTO frames, and after searching many times in RFC9001 for confirmation that (2) is the correct way, I still can't find the confirmation.

So, how does QUIC encrypt packets that contain multiple CRYPTO frames? Is there some specification in the RFCs for how this is done?

Comment: *assuming that [...] an unreasonable implementation could* - your assumptions do not match RFC specifications. If your code cannot analyze all QUICK packets then it's only suitable for a subset, even if that subset covers 99.9%.

Comment: @Zac67 That's actually why I'm asking this question, I want to handle 100%.